# Rabbit MQ Rejecting JSON with embeded List

Tags: java, json, rabbitmq, amqp

We have a AMQP messaging client forwarding the following message to a RabbitMQ server:

```
DEBUG - ObservationGroupTopic      -  [x] Sent {
  "uniqueIdentifier" : "11111111",
  "ward" : "WARD",
  "observationDate" : 1447626600000,
  "requestDate" : 1447333200000,
  "specimenReceivedDate" : 1447637400000,
  "statusDate" : 1447647660000,
  "status" : "F",
  "groupServiceCode" : "XM",
  "groupServiceDescription" : "CROSS MATCH",
  "observationUnitList" : [ ]
}
```

This works correctly.  However, if we extend the JSON with List elements:

```
{
  "uniqueIdentifier" : "1111111",
  "ward" : "WARD",
  "observationDate" : 1447635600000,
  "requestDate" : 1447160400000,
  "specimenReceivedDate" : 1447638060000,
  "statusDate" : 1447647660000,
  "status" : "P",
  "groupServiceCode" : "MC",
  "groupServiceDescription" : "MICRO/CULTURE",
  "observationUnitList" : [ {
    "valueType" : "NM",
    "value" : "0.0",
    "units" : null,
    "referenceRange" : null,
    "observationTypeCode" : "5803-2",
    "observationTypeDescription" : "pH",
    "abnormalFlag" : "U",
    "status" : "P",
    "observationDateTime" : 1447647660000
  } ]
}
```

The message fails to send with an error

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already closed due to clean connection shutdown; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK, class-id=0, method-id=0)
```

This is repeatable with every similarly structured message failing.  I am guessing that there is a message issue and RabbitMQ is telling the connection to "go-away"?

Is there something wrong with our message structure?  Is there an issue with "nulls"?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be my error - I was closing the connection outside a catch clause rather than inside - apologies for the hassle...